# how can I merge two RDD[string] together in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two RDD[string],one is label, another one is feature. They have same lines. How can i merge them line by line?

```
feature: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
res127: String = 11,0,7,18
label: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
res160: String = 1
```

each of them has thousands of lines while i just put the first line of them.
I want to have a new RDD[String] which every line looks like this

```
res: String = 1,11,0,7,18
```

I tried join(),it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using scala, I think, try `feature ++ label`

```
def ++(other: RDD[T]): RDD[T]
Return the union of this RDD and another one.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using zip? This would give you a key value pair for each of the labels and features. You could them keep them in this style for ease of access of the two components, or convert them to a singular string if that is what is required.

Alternativly, if you are just appending the label onto the front of the list, union is more appropriate. This could be prefixed with a foreach/filter to remove the unwanted labels.